# How to store user search queries in SharePoint Online in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, csom, sharepoint-search, search-api

I want to store the user search queries which are entered in the search box in a list and display them in a page without duplicates. I know I can get the excel report from popularity and search reports but not able to get them programatically in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to roll this yourself. There is no API for user query history at this time. As for storing it in a list, that would be easy. Then you can make the queries clickable by linking them to your search center using the `k=` query string parameter.